# How to get Matlab to join tables when join key is not unique

Tags: sql, matlab, join

I have this problem:

```
table1 = table([1 1 2 2].', [1 2 3 4].');
table2 = table([1 1 2 2].', [100 200 300 400].');
table2.Properties.VariableNames{2} = 'Var3';
join(table1, table2)
```

which gives (in 2015b)

```
>> join(table1, table2)
Error using table/join (line 111)
The key variable for B must have unique values.
```

The `join` command is nice because it preserves original row ordering of `table1`, however it cannot deal with duplicate key values in `table2` or missing key values. The commands `innerjoin` and `outerjoin` can, but reorder the rows according to the keys.

I would like the new function to behave like SQL so that if there are duplicate values the cross product is used, i.e. the output should be:

```
ans = 

    Var1    Var2    Var3
    ____    ____    ____

    1       1       100 
    1       2       100 
    1       1       200 
    1       2       200 
    2       3       300 
    2       4       300 
    2       3       400 
    2       4       400
```

and implement this so that the final dataset preserves the original ordering of rows in the first table, followed by the second table.

Comment: This may sound like a hack, but what not simply sort it afterward?

Comment: that sounds good in principle. One problem is that `innerjoin` and `outerjoin` does not work when the tables themselves contain nested tables.